# Changing the content of a UI element with a button press

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Google UI App that is designed to assist entering data into a google spreadsheet where most of the rows are identical.  To do so an UI panel is created and text fields are used for each column of the spreadsheet.  With the push of a button these values are appended to the spreadsheet.

I would like the button to then clear the contents of a single text box and maintain the values of the others to allow for entry of the next nearly identical item.  My attempts to do so have resulted in "Error encountered: Object does not allow properties to be added or changed."

I have included a simplified version below, the actual script has many text boxes but this simplified example also shares the problem.

```
function showNewEntryDialog() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle("Add Multiple Items");
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(9,3);
  var nameTextBox = app.createTextBox();
  var serialTextBox = app.createTextBox();
  nameTextBox.setName('nameTextBox').setId('nameTextBox');
  serialTextBox.setName('serialTextBox').setId('serialTextBox');
  var snButton = app.createButton('Add and New SN')
  grid.setWidget(0,0,app.createLabel('Name'));
  grid.setWidget(0,1,nameTextBox);
  grid.setWidget(4,0,app.createLabel('Serial Number'));
  grid.setWidget(4,1,serialTextBox);
  grid.setWidget(4,2,snButton);
  panel.add(grid);
  var snClickHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("respondToButtonPress");
  snButton.addClickHandler(snClickHandler);
  snClickHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
function respondToButtonPress(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([e.parameter.nameTextBox,
                   e.parameter.serialTextBox]);
  app.getElementById('serialTextBox').setText('');
  // Does nothing?

  app.getElementById('serialTextBox').setValue='';
  // Error:Object does not allow changes
}
```

How can a button change the contents of a text box in the UI panel?  If it cannot, in what other way can I achieve the behavior I desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bryan's answer is correct but you could do it more efficiently using a [clientHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/ui-service#ClientHandlers) in your main function like this :

```
function showNewEntryDialog() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  app.setTitle("Add Multiple Items");
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(9,3);
  var nameTextBox = app.createTextBox();
  var serialTextBox = app.createTextBox();
  nameTextBox.setName('nameTextBox').setId('nameTextBox');
  serialTextBox.setName('serialTextBox').setId('serialTextBox');
  var snButton = app.createButton('Add and New SN')
  grid.setWidget(0,0,app.createLabel('Name'));
  grid.setWidget(0,1,nameTextBox);
  grid.setWidget(4,0,app.createLabel('Serial Number'));
  grid.setWidget(4,1,serialTextBox);
  grid.setWidget(4,2,snButton);
  panel.add(grid);
  // a clientHandler : ----------------------------------------------------------
  var cHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(serialTextBox).setText('');
  //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  var snClickHandler = app.createServerClickHandler("respondToButtonPress");
  snButton.addClickHandler(snClickHandler).addClickHandler(cHandler);// you can have multiple handlers on the same widget
  snClickHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  app.add(panel);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
function respondToButtonPress(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([e.parameter.nameTextBox,
                   e.parameter.serialTextBox]);
}
```

Comment: To be clear for others, the two lines added are: var cHandler = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(serialTextBox).setText(''); AND 
snButton.addClickHandler(cHandler);

Comment: Thought the client handler would clear the value as well before posting to the sheet, but guess it doesn't. I typically like to see the text remain in input fields until a successful server return. Don't have to re-type it if an error occurs.  Just disabling the input on the client side would be nice though.

Answer (score 0):

Think `.setText()` and `.setValue()` essentially do the same thing so really only need one or the other. Your `.setValue=''` is invalid. Should be `.setValue('')`. Need a `return app;` at the end too.

Comment: Good suggestions, I've tried them but .setValue('') does not work either, it returns an error that the object does not allow properties to be changed.  Adding return app; also appears not to change the behavior.

Comment: `return app` goes in `respondToButtonPress` function. just using .setText seemed to work for me.